# How to add embedded field with matching documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm using Python with pymongo to query from the database.

I have 3 different collections:

1st:

```
# Projects collection
{
    "_id": "A",
},
{
    "_id": "B",
},
{
    "_id": "C"
},
..
```

2nd:

```
# Episodes collection
{
    "_id": "A/Episode01",
    "project": "A",
    "name": "Episode01"
},
{
    "_id": "A/Episode02",
    "project": "A",
    "name": "Episode02"
},
{
    "_id": "B/Episode01",
    "project": "B",
    "name": "Episode01"
},
..
```

3rd:

```
# Sequences collection
{
    "_id": "A/Episode01/Sequence01",
    "project": "A",
    "episode": "Episode01",
    "name": "Sequence01"
},
{
    "_id": "A/Episode02/Sequence02",
    "project": "A",
    "episode": "Episode02",
    "name": "Sequence02"
},
{
    "_id": "B/Episode01/Sequence01",
    "project": "B",
    "episode": "Episode01",
    "name": "Sequence01"
},
..
```

I want to use aggregate to query project `A` and get all of its corresponding episodes and sequences like this:

```
{
    "_id": "A",
    "episodes": 
    [
        {
            "_id": "A/Episode01",
            "project": "A",
            "name": "Episode01",
            "sequences": 
            [
                {
                    "_id": "A/Episode01/Sequence01",
                    "project": "A",
                    "episode": "Episode01",
                    "name": "Sequence01"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "A/Episode02",
            "project": "A",
            "name": "Episode02",
            "sequences":
            [
                {
                    "_id": "A/Episode02/Sequence02",
                    "project": "A",
                    "episode": "Episode02",
                    "name": "Sequence02"
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I can get as far as getting the proper episodes, but I'm not sure how to add an embed field for any matching sequences. Is it possible to do this all in a single pipeline query?

Right now my query is looking like this:

```
[
    {"$match": {
        "_id": "A"}
    },
    {"$lookup": {
        "from": "episodes",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "project",
        "as": "episodes"}
    },
    {"$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "episodes": "$episodes"}
    }}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like following

1. use `$match` to match the document
2. use [uncorrelated queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to join two collection. But normal joining also possible as you have written. This is easier when we get some complex situations.

Mongo script is given below

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "A"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Episodes",
      let: {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$project",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "Sequences",
            let: {
              epi: "$name"
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$episode",
                      "$$epi"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            as: "sequences"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "episodes"
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N9xvadenEku)**

---

**Update 01**

Using standard lookup

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "A"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Episodes",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "project",
      "as": "episodes"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$episodes"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Sequences",
      "localField": "episodes.name",
      "foreignField": "episode",
      "as": "episodes.sequences"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$episodes._id",
      episodes: {
        $addToSet: "$episodes"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EbXFj0AtBDK)**

Comment: I think my mongo version doesn't support `let` in lookup, as I'm on 3.2.3. Right now this gives me an error `$lookup must be strings, let: { id: "$_id" } is type 3`

Comment: Ohh. fine, then we will have more works with standard lookup. I will do and let you know

Comment: Wow that seems to work and it feels a lot more readable for me than the newer version. Just one issue I see is that it looks like it's finding sequences by episode name only. There could be other projects using the same name, so is it possible to match it with both the episode and project to prevent grabbing wrong entries?

Comment: NO, there is no way unless you use uncorrelated lookup. What you can do is, just to match and remove n another stage

Comment: Would using `$filter` on another stage be the way to go to remove any conflicting entries?

Comment: If you can find out the specifc object, if would help you

Comment: Yes it does which is why I upvoted, but now I'm left with another problem of having tons of conflicting entries, so I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: I was able to put the episode's id in the sequence object so that I can use that to match with in $lookup. Not super ideal but it does give me the results I'm looking for, so I'll accept this answer.